# How to change “Open properties on select” setting programmatically?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Whenever I select an item/items programmatically, the properties panel pops-up, even the “Open properties on select” in setting is off.

I would like to enable/disable “Open properties on select”  option in the setting via code.
What property of the viewer should I change?

Or please let me know if there is a way to to prevent opening properties when I select an item/items programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find all those options under the `viewer.prefs` property.
The easiest thing is to look for them in the Browser's Developer Console via `NOP_VIEWER`:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/do-simple-viewer-api-tests-quickly

[image]

The one in question is named `openPropertiesOnSelect`